# how to create scenario of REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED when performing ssh to remote machine for testing

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, ssh-keygen

we want to cause status from linux remote machine that return

```
"@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r",
"@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @\r",
"@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r",
```

so we change the one of the character of the remote machine in local `/root/.ssh/known_host` file ( beta machine ) in order to give this simulation

but this not happens

when we do ssh to remote machine from beta machine as

```
ssh alpha1
```

we access to the remote machine without to get :

```
"@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r",
"@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @\r",
"@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r",
```

so how to simulate this scenario?

Comment: re-run `ssh-keygen -A` on the remote machine? Run `sshd` as a regular user on the same high port with different `-h` (host_key) options (and connect to it)? It's not clear what you're trying to simulate.

Comment: we run ssh-keygen -A on the remote machine , but still not get the scenario that we want

Comment: what you mean run - sshd ??

Comment: we are trying to simulate reinstall of OS of remote machine , as you know when you reinstall the OS , then identification change , and you cannot access by ssh

Comment: any other ideas , why it is so complicated this simulation ?

Comment: You can run `sshd` as a regular user, provided that it's listening on a port >= 1024. It's not complicated. I'll give you an example, though I don't know if that's what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be ways to do that by just messing with `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, but here's a solution using a `sshd` server running as a regular user:

```
mkdir -m 700 /tmp/ssh
ssh-keygen -qN '' -f /tmp/ssh/1st
ssh-keygen -qN '' -f /tmp/ssh/2nd
/usr/sbin/sshd -h /tmp/ssh/1st -p 2222 -o PidFile=/tmp/ssh/pid
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 2222 localhost true
kill $(cat /tmp/ssh/pid)
/usr/sbin/sshd -h /tmp/ssh/2nd -p 2222 -o PidFile=/tmp/ssh/pid
```

And now:

```
% ssh -p 2222 localhost true
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Then `ssh-keygen -R [localhost]:2222`, rinse, repeat. It's up to you to instrumentalize it as you see fit.