# What kind of host key does the `sshd` command require?

Tags: ssh, sshd, key-authentication

The man page for [sshd](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/sshd) states the `-h` argument *Specifies a file from which to read a host key*.

But is it asking for the public host key or the private host key?

I can't seem to find this tidbit of information anywhere.

Comment: The private one. If you don't specify one, it will use a default (`/etc/ssh/ssh_host_${ALGO}_key`, which it may not be able to read if started as a regular user). You can use multiple `-h` arguments, for different algorithms. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/537734/308316) an example of `sshd -h `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The private host key.

This is the way SSHD learns the private key.

Answer (score 2):

It has to be the private key, it is how the `sshd` proves that it is who it says it is.

You know when you `ssh` to a server, and are told the fingerprint of the server. And you just blindly click `y`, because that is what the sys-admin, work colleague, or person on a forum told you to do. You are meant to check this fingerprint is correct, You need to get the fingerprint of the public key of the server through some other channel, that can't be spoofed.